# Issue while deploying angular 5 project +web api core in iis

Tags: iis, angular5, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have build my angular 5 app and set the Outdir to

[image]

and after that i published my web api core project.

I created a application under "Default Web site" in IIS

I updated the path to the publish folder and added a alias.

[image]

Now if i browse the app ,the api is working fine

but the wwwroot that exists under webapi publish folder doesnt work it seems.I am getting some 404 errors related to js and css files.

Dont know what exactly  iam missing to host the app.

[image]